# Easiest way to migrate static website to TYPO3 (HTML Template?)

Tags: html, templates, typo3

I have to migrate a static HTML website to TYPO3. I know, I could read docus first, but I believe I will need to read some days first to only recognize which direction to run...

Do I have to learn TypoScript like

```
Default PAGE
page = PAGE
page.typeNum = 0

page.20 = TEXT
page.20.value = HELLO UNIVERSE!

page.10 = TEXT
page.10.value = HELLO WORLD!
```

or is there another way to do it quickly? With markers?

thank you guys!

Answer (score 4):

You will have to learn a little bit of TypoScript to do what you want.  Sorry :-(  But you won't have to learn that much, and what you do learn you'll be able to reuse when building other TYPO3 sites.

First thing: skip markers.  Markers are a remnant of an old, deprecated templating system.  The way you should be doing this is with [TemplaVoila](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/extension-manuals/templavoila/1.5.2/view/).

TemplaVoila works by giving you an interface to map TYPO3 content (or instructions to generate content) to blocks of markup in your HTML file.  In other words, you take your static HTML file, then go through it and tell TemplaVoila "OK, that DIV is my sidebar, so put a list of all the site pages in there... that P is the footer, put a link to the privacy policy there... that DIV is the main content area, fill it with blocks of content created by the user," and so forth.  This is a very powerful approach, because it means that if you work with other Web designers or graphic designers, they don't have to learn any special "magic tags" or markers; they can just give you well-formed HTML and with a few clicks you can turn it into a live template for a site.  Pretty nifty.

There's a piece of TYPO3 documentation called ["Futuristic Template Building"](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/tutorials/doc_tut_ftb1/1.0.1/view/) that explains pretty clearly how to go from a static HTML page to a TYPO3-ized site with TemplaVoila. [Here's a direct link to the section of that doc that walks you through the process.](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/tutorials/doc_tut_ftb1/1.0.1/view/1/2/) (Don't be scared by the word "futuristic" into thinking that TemplaVoila isn't fully baked yet -- that doc was written six years ago, when TemplaVoila was pretty futuristic, but today it's quite mature and in use on TYPO3 sites all over the world.)

This should be enough to get you started, but if you hit roadblocks or can't wrap your head around it feel free to post your questions back to this thread and I'll help you out.

Comment: I agree, TemplaVoila is really the only way to get up and running quickly. For a good overview, I'd also recommend Kasper's video podcast demonstration where he built a site in an hour with TemplaVoila: http://castor.t3o.punkt.de/files/podkast_julestue3-build-website.m4v

Comment: wow, thank you for such detailed explanation! also thanks for the help offer ;-) I will order a video training as crash course.

Answer (score 3):

I'm reviving this, since a lot has happened since 2010.

There are multiple ways in TYPO3 to do the templating. All of them involve TypoScript, but in some there is only a minimal amount of TS needed.

1. Use "the old built-in way", doing all rendering in TypoScript and some HTML templates with markers in them. In this approach, you'd use the content elements provided by the core. Their rendering is defined with TypoScript in the core-extension "CSS Styled Content".
2. Use "the new built-in way". Here you'd also use the content elements provided by the core, and optionally self-defined ones. The rendering happens using the Fluid templating engine. You would do this using the core-extension "Fluid Styled Content". This is available since [version 7.5](https://typo3.org/news/article/typo3-cms-75-is-here-time-to-score/#c6114).
3. Use a third party extension for content element rendering. I know of these:

   - [Templavoilà](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/templavoila/) - You probably should not use it, since it is not actively developed anymore, although there is a version claiming compatibility to TYPO3 7 LTS, but I don't know much about that.
   - [FluidTYPO3](https://fluidtypo3.org/) - This is a whole ecosystem of extensions with which you can define page templates and content element templates completely using the Fluid Templating engine (backend forms, backend preview and frontend rendering). It also provides a mechanism for nesting content elements.
   - [DCE](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/dce/) - Dynamic content elements. I don't know anything about them, you would need to read the docs.
   - [Mask](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/mask/) - TYPO3-core near wizard for own contentelements and pagetemplates. Uses database fields, not flexforms.
   - More extensions I don't know of.

It would be a bit much to explain all of these here in detail. 
My current personal favorite is the FluidTYPO3 ecosystem, but I'm considering a switch to using Fluid Styled Content, because it is directly integrated into the core. I'm not sure if it supports nested content elements, so maybe one would need a separate solution for that (e.g. the extension `gridelements`).