# Migrate existing content (HTML) into TYPO website

Tags: html, static, import, typo3, migrate

I have a number of Webpages which I would like to import (automatically, not manually) into an existing TYPO3 website. A template and styles already exist. All webpages which are to be imported have the actual content (boilerplate is to be discarded) inside a single "div" element. I am thinking that this "div" might be imported into an RTE htmlArea. What is the best way to get started?

I already looked at this related post:
[Easiest way to migrate static website to TYPO3 (HTML Template?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4250739/easiest-way-to-migrate-static-website-to-typo3-html-template)

But it seems to describe how to use existing html pages as a template.

Answer (score 0):

Writing an extension that will extract code from HTML and import it as RTE is quite difficult task and I really advice you to do it manually.

TYPO3's structure it's not only single field in DB - it creates separate record in `tt_content`, related with some record from `pages`, RTE text is 'flattened' etc. etc. Such import requires good knowledge of the topic (and also lot of testing) so if you have less than 200 - 300 pages it's not worthy of the effort (IMHO)